# How to delete selected array of documents in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I had to find stores to remove their ids from their members, so I have them selected and I guess it's not a good idea to use the same query with deleteMany.here is my code:

```
async function deleteStores() {
  const stores = await Store.find({
    $or: [
      { deleteDate: { $exists: true, $gt: Date.now() } },
      { expires: { $gt: Date.now() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } },
    ],
  }).populate("members");

  const memberIds = [];
  stores.forEach((store) => {
    memberIds.push(...store.members.map((m) => m.account));
  });

  const storeIds = stores.map((s) => s.id);
  await Account.updateMany(
    { _id: { $in: memberIds } },
    { $pull: { stores: { $in: storeIds } } }
  );
  // what shall I do here to delete "stores"?
}
```

I'm new in mongodb, please feel free to make my code better.

```
// here are my schemas

const storeSchema = new Schema({
  // ... some other stuff
  members: [memberSchema],
  expires: { type: Date, default: () => Date.now() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
  deleteDate: Date,
});

const memberSchema = new Schema({
  account: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Account" },
  memberType: { type: Number, enum: Object.values(MemberType), default: 3 }, // MemberType
  access: [{ type: String, enum: Object.values(MemberAccess) }], // MemberAccess
});

const AccountSchema = new Schema({
  // ... some other stuff
  stores: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Store" }],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is almost OK, after you pulled out the store ids from Accounts, you should delete Stores by ids:

```
await Store.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: storeIds } })
```

As I can see you use Mongoose, so you should use `_id` in your code not `id`. If your code doesn't delete `store` references from Accounts that's why I guess.

In your code you have a `forEach` over stores to collect member ids and after you map the store ids, I think it's more optimal to collect store ids in that `forEach` too:

```
const accountIds = [];
const storeIds = [];

stores.forEach((store) => {
  storeIds.push(store._id);
  accountIds.push(...store.members.map((m) => m.account));
});
```

I should rename `memberIds` to `accountIds` because it's a collection of Account ids (not Member), it can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to know if it's ok to have this line of code at the end 
"await Store.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: storeIds } })"